# Sign up failure after form validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to java script coding. I have a sign in form that takes username, password and email. It validates three of these and doesn't proceed to the next "logout.php" page and dont even alert if the id has been already taken. It only validates the entries of the text boxes. I want to validate three of these entries of form first and then if they are valid and id is unique then clicking submit "logout.php" should get opened.
Below is my code:

**sign-up.php**

```
<form method="post" name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation();">

<input type="text" placeholder="Id*" required=" "  name="uid">

<input type="password" placeholder="Password*" required=" " name="passid">

<input type="text" placeholder="Emailaddress*" required=" " name="uemail">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger; color: white; background-color: #FFA500; border: 3pt ridge lightgrey">
                        </form>
```

Java script code for validation:

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formValidation()
{
var uid = document.registration.uid;
var passid = document.registration.passid;
var uemail = document.registration.uemail;


if(userid_validation(uid,5,12))
{

if(passid_validation(passid,7,12))
{

if(ValidateEmail(uemail))
{
}
}
}
return false;
}


function userid_validation(uid,mx,my)
{
var uid_len = uid.value.length;
if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx)
{
alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);
uid.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}

function passid_validation(passid,mx,my)
{
var passid_len = passid.value.length;
if (passid_len == 0 ||passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx)
{
alert("Password should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);
passid.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}


function ValidateEmail(uemail)
{
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(uemail.value.match(mailformat))
{
//alert("You have entered a valid email address!");
return true;
}
else
{
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
uemail.focus();
return false;
}
}
```

The PHP part checks if the id has been already taken or not. This part of the code is not being executed after clicking submit button. None of the messages get displayed from this part of code.

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open('trip.db');
        }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {

    }
    $id=null;
    $pass=null;
    $email=null;
    $id_exists=false;

    if (isset($_POST['uid'])) {
        $id = $_POST['uid'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['passid'])) {
        $pass = $_POST['passid'];
    }

      if (isset($_POST['uemail'])) {
        $email = $_POST['uemail'];
    }



    $result= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE ID = '".$id. "';" ;
    $count= $db->querySingle($result);

    if ($count > 0)
    {
        $id_exists = true;
        echo "This id is not available. Please enter a valid id. ";
    }

    else
    {
        $sql= " INSERT INTO Users (ID, PASSWORD, EMAIL)
          VALUES ('$id','$pass','$email'); " ;
        $ret = $db->query($sql);
        $_SESSION['Id'] = $id;
        header("location:logout.php");
    }


    $db->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sample code.

```js
 function test_js() {
 if(document.test_form.id.value == "") {
  alert('input name!');
  document.test_form.id.focus();
  return;
 } else {
  document.test_form.action = "logout.php";
  document.test_form.submit();
 }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="login.php" name="test_form">
        <input type="text" name="id">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:test_js();">
</form>
```

Comment: I dont want to check if the text box is empty or not because that has already been handled by my javascript code. The problem now is that after validation the php part isnt running

Comment: i think you don`t write **action** in code. 
**<form method="post" action="next.php" name="registration">**

Comment: i tried doing it with action too but it didnt help :(